# View not getting updated after @Published property is modified async in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mobile

> Inb4: swift/swiftUI newbie
> also found several posts about people getting stuck at this, but i
> couldn't see the difference between what they were doing and what I'm
> doing, that's why I'm posting a new question

**Background**

I'm trying to create an app state object, that the UI can use to make changes at a global scale. I'm posting a screenshot so it's all visible in one go
[image]

I'm initialising the `AppState` and add that to the environment and pass it to the `ContentView` which is my apps root view.

I inject the `appState` into `ContentView` and when building the view i'm having a switch so that i can hide/show my main views: logged in view, logged out view, no internet view etc.

The switch should react to the `currentRoute` variable which is part of `ViewRouting` class

```
class ViewRouting: ObservableObject, Equatable {
    
    static let shared = ViewRouting()
    
    @Published var currentRoute: MainRoutes {
        willSet {
            print("Setting current route to \(newValue)")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue.rawValue, forKey: "currentRoute")
        }
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: ViewRouting, rhs: ViewRouting) -> Bool {
        return lhs.currentRoute == rhs.currentRoute
    }
    
    private init() {
        currentRoute = .loggedOut
    }
}
```

**Problem**

I've first discovered this when trying to update the `currentRoute` in case the internet goes down/up. But the posted example works too. Modifying the `currentRoute` in an async block doesn't make the UI react and redraw.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

Created [repo](https://github.com/alexantonica/test-ios-app-stackovrfl) that reproduces this

Comment: It would probably be easier to find an answer to your question, if you just provided a minimal example which demonstrates the issue. Also, I am not that convinced regarding the architecture. For example, you are still handling logic in the views, eventhough using a "Model" (ObservableObject) where it should be handled. When you use a model, try to make views as "dumb" as possible. Also, you should use an "unidrectional" approach, i.e. from the view only _read_ from a binding and send "intents" to the model - never directly change the binding from the view.

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment. I ve specified that the DispatchQueue code is there to make it easier to show everything in as little code as possible. In my real code that part is in a service.

Comment: Alex, I created a minimal example, and it worked as expected. Precisely, when the async function will be executed, the published property will be changed. As a result, the body of the view - where the appState is provided via the Environment - will be recomputed.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper https://github.com/alexantonica/test-ios-app-stackovrfl Not sure if you have the same setup. I've created a repo if you have time to check it. It's not working for me. If you run it and check the console, the `willSet` prints the right value but the view doesn't change

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
I've changed `UserData` `ViewRouting` and `System` to `struct` instead of classes so that the mutation is propagated to `AppState`

---

For anyone stuck in the same situation, I found the solution in this [post](https://forums.swift.org/t/is-it-possible-to-get-send-a-published-variable-value-through-a-chain-of-classes/41404/2)

In case the link will break some time in the future, here's a summary:

Given OPs problem having chained `@Published` properties, just like me

```
class Score: ObservableObject {   
    @Published var num = 0   
}

class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var score = Score()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var settings = UserSettings()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Your score is \(settings.score.num)")
            Button(action: {
                self.settings.score.num += 1
            }) {
                Text("Increase Score")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reply accepted as an answer
[image]

---